Discord API responding with "Request failed with status code 401"
I am developing a discord servers list, the site itself is complete, but I am having major issues ever since switching to slash commands (requirement for verification, unless approved for Message Intent). Basically what I am trying to accomplish (and what was working prior to switching to slash commands) is when my bot joins a guild, an admin can type: /setup - this command is supposed to get the guild id, approx. member count, server icon and send the information to my database (api/update-database.php) where server_id = ?.
Prior to switching, this worked by typing !setup. Now I am lost, the console is telling me: Error updating guild data: Request failed with status code 401.
The bot token is set correctly in my .env file, as well as the client ID.
Here is my commands/api/setup.js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require("discord.js");
const axios = require("axios");

async function sendInviteLinkToServer(guildId, inviteUrl) {
  const apiUrl = "http://localhost/discord-servers/api";

  try {
    // Fetch server details from Discord API
    const guildDetailUrl = `https://discord.com/api/guilds/${guildId}?with_counts=true`;
    const response = await axios.get(guildDetailUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.BOT_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });

    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch guild details:", response.statusText);
      return;
    }

    const guildDetailData = response.data;
    if (guildDetailData) {
      const server_image = guildDetailData.icon
        ? `https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/${guildId}/${guildDetailData.icon}.png`
        : "https://localhost/discord-servers/images/site/no-image-available.png";

      const user_count = guildDetailData.approximate_member_count || 0;

      // Log data to console before making the POST request
      console.log("Data to be sent to update-database.php:");
      console.log("Server ID:", guildId);
      console.log("Server Image:", server_image);
      console.log("User Count:", user_count);

      // Make a POST request to update-database.php
      const updateDatabaseUrl = apiUrl + "/update-database.php";
      const updateData = {
        server_id: guildId,
        server_image: server_image,
        user_count: user_count,
        invite_url: inviteUrl, // include the invite URL in the data
      };

      const headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      };

      const dbResponse = await axios.post(updateDatabaseUrl, updateData, {
        headers,
      });
      console.log("Database updated successfully:", dbResponse.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error updating guild data: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("setup")
    .setDescription("Setup the invite link for the servers listing on redacted")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator),
  async execute(interaction) {
    // Ensure the interaction is in a guild
    if (!interaction.guild) {
      await interaction.reply("This command can only be used in a server.");
      return;
    }

    // Check if user has administrative permissions
    if (
      !interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)
    ) {
      await interaction.reply(
        "You need to have administrator permissions to use this command."
      );
      return;
    }

    // Fetch the bot's member object
    let botMember;
    try {
      botMember = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(
        interaction.client.user.id
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch bot member object:", error);
      await interaction.reply(
        "An error occurred while checking my permissions."
      );
      return;
    }

    // Ensure the bot has the correct permissions
    const botPermissions = interaction.channel.permissionsFor(botMember);
    if (!botPermissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages)) {
      await interaction.reply(
        "I don't have the permission to send messages in this channel."
      );
      console.error("Bot lacks SendMessages permission in the channel.");
      return;
    }

    if (!botPermissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.CreateInstantInvite)) {
      await interaction.reply("I don't have the permission to create invites.");
      console.error("Bot lacks CreateInstantInvite permission in the channel.");
      return;
    }

    // Get the channel to create an invite for
    const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (channel) =>
        channel.type === 0 && // 0 corresponds to GUILD_TEXT
        channel
          .permissionsFor(botMember)
          .has(PermissionFlagsBits.CreateInstantInvite)
    );

    if (!channel) {
      await interaction.reply(
        "Could not find a suitable channel to create an invite."
      );
      console.error("No suitable channel found for creating an invite.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const invite = await channel.createInvite({
        maxAge: 0, // Infinite duration
        maxUses: 0, // Unlimited uses
      });

      try {
        await interaction.reply(
          `Successfully created an invite link and updated http://localhost.`
        );
        console.log("Message sent successfully.");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to send message:", error);
      }

      // Send the invite link to the local server using Axios
      await sendInviteLinkToServer(interaction.guild.id, invite.url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating invite:", error);
      await interaction.reply("There was an error creating the invite link.");
    }
  },
};



Not sure if this is needed but I will post it anyway, update-database.php:
if (isset($_POST['server_id'], $_POST['server_image'], $_POST['user_count'])) {
    // Retrieve POST data
    $server_id = $_POST['server_id'];
    $server_image = $_POST['server_image'];
    $user_count = $_POST['user_count'];

    // Example query: Update guild details
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE servers SET server_image = ?, user_count = ? WHERE server_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $server_image, $user_count, $server_id);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Database updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating database: " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "Missing POST data";
}


I removed the need for the API on my update-database.php to see if that was the issue, it was not. I am unsure what to do next, Discord.js is new to me!
